# Elegant alternative to long exception chains?

Tags: python

A lot of times I find myself writing something that looks like this:

```
try:
    procedure_a()
except WrongProcedureError:
    try:
        procedure_b()
    except WrongProcedureError:
        try:
            procedure_c()
        except WrongProcedureError:
            give_up()
```

This is hideous. Is there a more elegant way to implement this kind of "try things until one doesn't exception" logic? It seems like this is the kind of thing that would come up a lot; I'm hoping there's some language feature I don't know about that's designed for this exact thing.

Comment: Loops. You're looking for loops. Doing the same thing multiple times is what loops are for.

Comment: I would be interested to know the real case here... if you're doing it a lot, then maybe the code can be re-structured to not need to do this? It does look like it might be tricky to reason about what the code does in any given situation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a `for/else` construct for this:

```
for proc in [procedure_a, procedure_b, procedure_c]:
    try:
        proc()
    except WrongProcedureError:
        continue
    else:
        break
else:
    give_up()
```

The `else` clause of the `for` loop triggers only when control falls off the bottom of the for clause naturally. If you `break` out (as you will if any of the three procedures do not throw an exception), it won't trigger.

Comment: couldn't that just be `proc(); break` instead of having an `else:` clause in the `try:` block?

Comment: @fferri sure could! YMMV, but I like the `try/except/else`. Even when it's something obvious like "`break`", it seems good to explicitly show that the `break` is not the code I'm expecting to fail.

Answer (score 5):

Loop through procedures. Wrap the loop into a function. Return from the function prematurely in case of success:

```
def try_all():
    for procedure in [procedure_a, procedure_b, procedure_c]:
        try:
            procedure()
            return
        except WrongProcedureError:
            continue
    give_up()
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually there's nothing wrong with your approach. It uses ordinary language features and conveys its message pretty clear.

The other approaches also work but they are somewhat more complicated to understand and probably only preferable in case you have lots (not only 3) functions that you want to check. In that case I would actually make a function to hide that complexity.

```
import itertools
from contextlib import suppress

def call_functions(funcs, give_up_func):
    for func in itertools.chain(funcs, [give_up_func]):
        with suppress(WrongProcedureError):
            func()
            return  # only reached when func does not raise WrongProcedureError.
```

That assumes that `give_up_func` won't raise that Exception and `suppress` requires python 3 (i think 3.4).

However there might be something fundamentally wrong in your code when you actually need this. This seems like some sort of "fallback" operation that probably should be solved using subclasses or an additional argument or a strategy/factory instead of nested `try` and `except`s.